# Why do Priest and Elf-girl care about how they kill Goblins?

Tags: goblin-slayer

In modern times, we have things like international law, the geneva convention, the US constitution, and other rules/structures guarding against chemical and biological attacks, cruel and inhumane punishment, etc.

In the context of the world of the anime, it's clear they don't have organizations like that, similar rules, etc.

> They are just getting to the point where they are thinking about teaching and training within the Guild.  Which is pretty rudimentary as far as things go.

Why would Priest and Elf girl try to prevent Goblin Slayer from using fire, water, or poison to kill Goblins (in ep 6)?  Especially given that they've both been traumatized by Goblins.

Comment: isn't it because they are scared they also will hurt the village and its people?

Comment: I don't think Prestess ever made a fuss about Goblin Slayer's methods, she's just been shown to be put-off by what is essentially a hero in her eyes using underhanded and inhumane methods, which is understandable. High-elf archer was a lot more vocal, and in her case it's because it goes against her ideals of what an adventurer should be.

Comment: I would prefer goblin slayer using his own method.... He is not an adventurer, he is a specialist.